# Is this statement about this function true?

Tags: polynomials

Let's say we have a polynomial  function. Let's suppose that there is an infinite set M, with the following property: $\forall x \in M, f(x) = 1$.
Is it true that $f(x)=X$?

And if it is, then why?

Comment: What is X here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A short proof : A polynomial of degree n has at most n roots. Suppose that f is of degree $n \geq 1$. Consider the polynomial f-1, it is of degree n, and has an infinite number of zeros : contradiction.

Comment: I want to tank both of you for your answers. They were very good and compete, and it gave two different solutions to the same problem. I love when this happens. Because he was first, I chose Tryss's answer as telher winner.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you mean "is it true that $f(x) = 1$", then yes.

I imagine that there are various arguments, here is a (possibly too slow, but, it only uses calculus) one.

As $f$ is a polynomial it is infinitely differentiable, and, all its derivates are polynomials (in decreasing degree). As $f$ has value $1$ at infinitely many points, by Rolle's theorem, $f'$ has infinitely many $0$s. As $f'$ has infinitely many $0$s, then $f''$ has infinitely many $0$s (again Rolle's), this keeps going forever. If $f$ has degree $n>0$, then, we know that $f^{(n)}$ is a constant *non-zero* polynomial, yet it must also have infinitely many $0$s, a contradiction.

Hence the degree of $f$ is $0$, i.e. $f$ is a constant polynomial, and, thus it must be $f(x) = 1$.